# Why do I get the error "'SequentialFeatureSelector' object has no attribute 'predict'"?

Tags: classification, svm, feature-selection, gridsearchcv

I am trying to do sequential feature selection in Python and would like to select the number of features through GridsearchCV, can someone help me with understanding why this happens?

```py
X_SFS=X_train_normed
numbers = [x for x in range(1,19)]

svc = SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.1, C = 10)

sfs = SequentialFeatureSelector(estimator=svc)

param_grid = [{'k_features':numbers}]

search = GridSearchCV(sfs, param_grid, cv=StratifiedKFold(5, shuffle=False), scoring='f1_macro')
search.fit(X_SFS, y_train)
svm_params.append(search.best_params_)
features_bool.append(search.best_estimator_.named_steps['sfs'].get_support())
scores.append(search.best_score_)
```

The above throws the error:

```
AttributeError: 'SequentialFeatureSelector' object has no attribute 'predict'
```